Did Dummett botch his anti-realism?
Michael Dummett's 1963 essay "The philosophical significance of Gödel's theorem" is considered one of the earliest formulations of an anti-realist position.  But did Dummett do a good job in presenting his case?  Dummett writes the following about the Gödel sentence U:

"to say that we recognize U as true by recognizing that a model in which it was false would be non-standard makes it look as though what we were here doing was to appeal to a principle of distinction between standard and non-standard models not incorporated in the formal system, thereby obscuring the fact that this distinction cannot be explained at all except except by means of the notion of 'the natural number' or something allied like 'numeral'.  In fact, the transition from saying that all of the statements A(0), A(1), A(2),... are true to saying that ∀() is trivial." (page 146).

Here Dummett is seeking to reject a Platonist reading of Gödel's incompleteness theorem, by questioning a distinction between standard and nonstandard models. This would be consistent with Abraham Robinson's views.  Indeed, Robinson similarly rejected the existence of a putative standard model a.k.a. "the intended interpretation" (of course, in nonstandard analysis the term standard is used in a relative sense; thus, any given model is referred to as standard, and its ultrapower would then be nonstandard).  But then Dummett appears to make a blunder by assuming that a numeral is the same as a natural number. This could be read as a blunder because natural numbers are part of the object language, and numerals are generally regarded as metalanguage integers; this seems to be Sergei Artemov's approach as well.
Furthermore, the transition from A(0), A(1), A(2), ... to ∀() is not trivial at all, contrary to what Dummett claims.  The former can be read as a schema indexed by metalanguage integers whereas the latter is a statement in the formal language.  In fact, this distinction is essential for Artemov's theorem on the provability of CON^S(PA) within PA; see e.g., this MO discussion.  So Dummett's blunder seems to be to pay insufficient attention to the distinction between metalanguage and object language.
Dummett's article has been fairly influential, and highly cited (over 200 citations in Google Scholar).
Note.  There are certain assertions in Dummett's piece that I find inscrutable and I would even venture to say that most mathematicians would find inscrutable, such as his claim that there is a

"gap between being able, for each numeral n-bar,  to recognize that A(n-bar) is true, and being able to recognize that, for every numeral n-bar, A(n-bar) is true" (emphasis added).

Modern mathematics does not seem to recognize such a difference between "each" and "every".
To summarize, at metalanguage level, one has a schema of sentences A(1), A(2), A(3) whereas in object language, the sentence ∀n A(n). These are inequivalent as I elaborated above. But this is not what Dummett says. He makes two claims: (1) "the transition from saying that all of the statements A(0), A(1), A(2),... are true to saying that ∀() is trivial"; (2) with regard to numerals (i.e., at metalanguage level), there is a difference between an assertion using "each" and and assertion using "every". Both of his claims seem incorrect.
Question. Has the particular aspect of Dummett's position as outlined above been criticized and/or defended in the follow-up literature?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Dummett does not question the distinction between standard and nonstandard models. His position is that when Platonists claim that a Gödel sentence is unprovable but true in some model, they are misusing the concept of model. He says:

The mistake in the account we are considering lies, rather, in the
misapplication of the notion of a model. This notion has, in the
context of some particular suitable mathematical theory, a quite
precise content... In such cases we are talking about the models
within the framework of a mathematical theory by means of which the
models can be described. The account of Gödel's theorem we are
considering, however, operates with a notion of a model as if it were
something that could be given to us independently of any
description... This has nothing to do with the concept of a model as
that concept is legitimately used in mathematics. (pp. 190-191.)
My argument has been, not that there is no such one standard model,
still less that there is any uncertainty about which particular
objects we shall recognise as natural numbers, but that the notion of
'model' here used is incoherent. (p. 193.)

Dummett does not confuse numbers and numerals. He uses the overbar notation to indicate a numeral.
For Dummett, Gödel's result shows that there is no single way to specify what it means for a mathematical statement to be true.

The only way to explain the meanings of quantification over the
natural numbers is to state the principles for recognising as true a
statement which involves it; Gödel's discovery amounted to the
demonstration that the class of these principles cannot be specified
exactly once for all, but must be acknowledged to be an indefinitely
extensible class. (p. 199.)

Hence under Dummett's intuitionism, Gödel's theorem does not show that truth outruns provability, as Platonists would have it, but rather that both truth and provability are indefinitely extensible.

... A mathematical proof or construction is essentially a mental
entity, something that may be capable of being represented by an
arrangement of symbols on paper, but cannot be identified with it...
The intuitive conception of a valid mathematical proof, even for
statements within some circumscribed theory, cannot in general be
identified with the concept of a proof within one formal system; for
it may be the case that no formal system can ever succeed in embodying
all the principles of proof that we should intuitively accept; and
this is precisely what is shown to be the case in regard to number
theory by Gödel's theorem. In this case, as we have seen, this simply
means that the class of intuitively acceptable proofs is an
indefinitely extensible one...  (p. 200.)

For Dummett, 'proof' is an inherently vague concept that is concerned with what we find intuitively acceptable and should not be conflated with proof within a formal system.
(My page numbers here refer to those in the reproduction of the paper in Dummett's Truth and Other Enigmas, Duckworth, 1978, pp. 186-201.)

Dummett writes: "It explains quantification over the natural numbers by means
of quantification over the numerals; and these, of course, form a
totality isomorphic to the natural numbers."  If so, what is the difference, according to Dummett, between a numeral and a natural number?  His text is obscure on this point.

@Bumble - Did you read: https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2019-March/021443.html (or Artemov's paper)?

@mudskipper from your link above, this sentence in the beginning part "The proof of G2 states that Con(PA) is not derivable in PA which, semantically, is equivalent to existing of a model M of PA in which Con(PA) fails."  is subtly wrong and very problematic, G2 famously assumes Con(PA) first (and never asserts or proves Con(PA) fails) and is just a special case of G1, both of which the standard model actually cannot prove their provability within PA as proved by Godel, some nonstandard models can actually prove the provability of both within PA which is not surprised actually...

Note that the https://mathoverflow.net/questions/469247/situation-with-artemovs-paper discussion may also help understand this better. Artemovs second paper has been accepted in the peer-reviewed Journal of Logic and Computation.

@DoubleKnot - You have to take into account that your quoted statement is rather informal and done in an informal general discussion. So you have to give hat statement a bit of wriggle room. A. knows perfectly well that from the assumption of Con(PA) the unprovability follows, that's not under discussion. -- So, it's better probably to refer to As papers instead of laying salt on all statements in the informal back and forth.

@mudskipper as exemplified by Kant, philosophy is intrinsically critiquing and critical, even in the informal back and forth, which is actually the norm everywhere including here especially it was you provided the above link to the public and asked for some kind of feedback about the so-called informal back and forth communication, wherefore 'laying salt' ought to be meant to be positively useful here imho...

@DoubleKnot -  Sure - My main point is just that the quoted statement is not incorrect.  G2 does state that Cons(PA) is not derivable in PA. This is indeed under the assumption that PA is consistent, but  of course if PA is assumed to be inconsistent then everything is derivable.

@mudskipper think for yourself, it doesn't make sense to say Con(PA) is a formalization of consistency of PA either in the standard or nonstandard model. Con(PA) is only formalized for the single theory of PA. Since G2 first assumes Con(PA) holds, if there were a model M of PA in which Con(PA) fails, then M simply isn't a model of PA. The subtle point here is Con(PA) like the more explicit G1 which are both self-referential meta-proposition, unlike usual schematic propositions like "for all n, ~Proof(n, 0=1)" in your provided references, otherwise w-logic can resolve incompleteness long ago...

The way I understand it - but my understanding may not be perfect - is that Con(PA) is a very specific formula, namely the formula in PA of ∀x ¬x:⊥ (where ':' denotes the relation of 'Proves' or 'Derives' between the gödel numbers of propositions). A model is a set-theoretic interpretation of the formulas of PA (so there are no models "in PA"). Truth or falsehood of formulas only is assigned by choosing a model. In the standard model of PA (where numbers just are the natural numbers) the formula Con(PA) is true. But there are other non-standard models in which Con(PA) fails.

In other words, Con(PA) is not identical to the (informal) claim or assumption that PA is consistent. It's also not a meta-proposition. It is a formula expressible in PA - which by construction, is provably unprovable.

I mean, we do actually assume that PA is consistent (informally). Right? The single theory of PA is purely formal and does not determine any model. The way natural numbers are defined in PA is also not identical to the set-theoretic definition of natural numbers (the von Neumann construction).

Quote from Gs paper himself (Prop XI): "... in particular, the consistency of P is unprovable in P, it being assumed that P is consistent (if not, of course, every statement is provable)."

But -- if you think it's Artemov who is misleading or incorrect in his interpretation - I would encourage you to go into discussion directly with him (see the earlier link I gave). He is of course far more knowledgable than me and would be able to answer you in a much better way. I would be interested in reading any discussion.

@mudskipper your Gödel quote above is exactly my point. Look, if in any theorem we first assume some assumption holds (syntactically) then why on earth the said assumption would fail in some mysterious model, assuming logic consistency. A model of a theory by definition has to hold for all specs of a theory as one of its implementation. Artemov’s argument is based on the completeness theorem of fol, but he overlooked Gödel’s completeness theorem is formalized under the mere perspective of fol where neither self-reference G1 nor more subtle meta-logic G2 is definable and applicable…

Interesting. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand your point or (for this context) the words you are using ("specs", "implementation"). But, please, I encourage you to tell Artemov that he made an elementary logical mistake (if that is your point). -- I mean, that's the beauty of the internet: we can talk to scientists directly (and they talk back!) (sometimes)
